# Tracking multiple subdiretories with Google Analytics when filters are already defined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a website say, `www.example.com` with subdirectories `www.example.com/sub1` and `www.example.com/sub2`. I have created 3 profiles in Google Analytics account. 'General', 'Sub1' & 'Sub2'. 'Sub1' & 'Sub2' have filters to only include subdirectories for each. My intention is to get information about hits to my website in 'General' profile **AND** information about hits to specific subdirectory 'Sub1' or 'Sub2' in the respective profile. I have added this in my JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Do I need to add anything else in my JS ?

Is there any advantage of including

```
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName',  '.example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/Sub1']);
```

in my JS ? I went through Google Analytics documents but could not find advantage of using this, if I have already defined filters in my account. Please shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `_setDomainName` or `_setCookiePath` are needed in your case.

`_setDomainName` is only needed if you're dealing with multiple domains and/or subdomains, like `www.example.com`, `sub1.example.com`, `www.example2.com`, etc.

`_setCookiePath` allows tracking of multiple distinct sites on a domain, but makes the general rollup tracking more difficult.

Google Analytics uses cookies to track things like session status, referral data, etc. 
Normally, root (/) is used as the default cookie path for an entire site. If you try using `setCookiePath` to set different paths for different parts of your site, the tracking data is going to be inconsistant across the whole site.
Since you have one site, but want different views of the data, only one cookie path is needed, and the default path will work.

FYI: Filters in Google Analytics are not retroactive -- they only apply to new tracking data coming in, not data that's already been recorded.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between having `_setCookiePath` in JS and having include only filter for the subdirectory in Google Analytics in account ? If I do not have `_setDomainName` in JS, will my subdomains be tracked ?

Comment: Subdomains or subdirectories -- sub1.example.com or www.example.com/sub1? If you don't have different domains or subdomains, then _setDomainName is not needed.

Comment: @Prabhat --  I added a little more explanation about cookies and setCookiePath to my answer.